# Prevent ASP.NET Identity's UserManager from automatically saving

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2

I'm attempting to integrate with ASP.NET Identity and its UserManager.  I have my own custom user object which I've added to the out-of-the-box ApplicationUser.  UserManager has a Create() method (actually it's in the UserManagerExtensions class) that creates a new user.  The problem is that it automatically saves the changes to the database which is confirmed [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn613290%28v=vs.108%29.aspx).  I've like to do some other operations in the same "transaction" before saving the new user so I can't have UserManager automatically save changes.

The interesting thing is that I'm overriding the SaveChange() method in the DbContext I'm associating to the UserManager, yet it never breaks in that method for the automatic save in Create().

Is there any way to configure UserManager to not automatically save changes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This feature already has been implemented in default `UserStore`. Therefore you just need to configure it. In `ApplicationUserManager.Create()` static method, or anywhere you are instantiating `UserStore`, set `AutoSaveChanges` to `false`.

```
public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options, IOwinContext context) 
{
    var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(
        new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()) 
             { AutoSaveChanges = false });

    // rest of codes
}
```